# How to write a meson build for a python package that replaces setup.py

Tags: python, conda, meson-build

I have a python package with multiple pure python modules with dependencies on other python packages that I want to move to the meson build system with the view of having backend libraries written in Fortran and C++ in the future. I am a total novice when it comes to meson build systems and would like a overview of how to create a meson build system to install a python package in a conda environment after checking dependencies.

My current attempt at the meson-build with mesonpep517, for the minimal python package is as follows:

```
project('cmbframe',
version: '0.5.0dev0',
license: 'GPL3+',
)

py_mod = import('python')

message('Looking for dependencies')
python = py_mod.find_installation(

if not python.found()
error('No valid python3 binary found')
else
message('Found python3 binary')
endif

if not python.language_version().version_compare('\>= 3.8')
error('Python 3.8 or newer is required.')
endif


py_install_dir = python.get_install_dir()
message('Meson will install python sources in', py_install_dir)

python.install_sources(\[
'cmbframe/__init__.py',
'cmbframe/em_law.py',
'cmbframe/hp_wrapper.py',
'cmbframe/Planck_colors.py',
'cmbframe/plot_utilts.py',
'cmbframe/UC_CC.py',
'cmbframe/version.py',
'cmbframe/wavelet.py',
'cmbframe/wmap_noise.py'\],
subdir: 'cmbframe'
)
```